# Pylons paster shell does not run in ipython

Tags: python, pylons, ipython

I install ipython, and then i run 
    `./paster shell dev.ini` 
command, paster open standard python console. How can I make it run ipython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem downgrading ipython to version 0.10

Answer (score 3):

Here's how it worked for me on Fedora 17 with IPython 0.12, paste-1.7.5.1 and pylons 1.0:

```
$ paster shell dev.ini
Pylons Interactive Shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 24 2012, 10:05:38) 
[GCC 4.7.0 20120507 (Red Hat 4.7.0-5)]

  All objects from project.lib.base are available
  Additional Objects:
  mapper     -  Routes mapper object
  wsgiapp    -  This project's WSGI App instance
  app        -  paste.fixture wrapped around wsgiapp

>>> __name__ = '__main__'
>>> import IPython
>>> IPython.embed()
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 24 2012, 10:05:38) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.12 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

Resetting `__name__` is necessary because either Pylons/Paste sets `__name__` to `"pylons-admin"` which confuses IPython (it tries to lookup the main module by its name in `sys.modules`).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the steps from the [Pylons Quick Site Development](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/pylons_quick_site.html#using-an-ipython-embedded-shell):

> 13.1.2   Using an IPython embedded shell
>
> IPython provides a more powerfull interactive prompt and a powerful
>   embedded shell. If you are a Python programmer and have not yet tried
>   IPython, you definitely should look into it.
>
> First, import from IPython -- Add something like the following at the
>   top of your controller module, in our case in
>   firstapp/controllers/firstcontroller.py:
>
> from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed args = ['-pdb', '-pi1', 'In
>   <\#>: ', '-pi2', '   .\D.: ',
>       '-po', 'Out<\#>: ', '-nosep'] ipshell = IPShellEmbed(args,
>       banner = 'Entering IPython.  Press Ctrl-D to exit.',
>       exit_msg = 'Leaving Interpreter, back to Pylons.')
>
> Then, place this code in your action/method:
>
> ipshell('We are at action abc')
>
> Return to Pylons and continue on responding to the request by pressing
>   Ctrl-D.
>
> Note that because of some idiosyncratic feature of
>   IPython.Shell.IPShellEmbed, I had to put the following before each
>   call to ipshell():
>
> ipshell.IP.exit_now = False ipshell('We are at action abc')

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that your ipython is installed globally, but that you're running pylons from a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) that is `--no-site-packages`?  If that's the case, then pylons won't see your installation of ipython.

Answer (score 0):

Ipython updated to version .11 just recently. Some of the components no longer work correctly, especially with 3rd party libraries. Check the mailing lists for pylons, and you may want to consider a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
paster ishell dev.ini
```